# jQuery Doesn't see AngularJS template ngRepeat injected

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular and i just started inserting it to my working website.

I'm trying to use [this example](http://www.bloglovin.com/viewer?post=1282307729&group=0&frame_type=l&blog=9770311&frame=1&click=0&user=0) as a "scroll into view" plugin to detect DOM elements being scrolled in the view.

When i use ngRepeat directive to insert data, even local data, the jquery plugin can't see the loaded data. still sees an empty container.

how can i handle it?

```
<div class="row scrolling" ng-repeat="item in projects">
 <span>{{item.name}}</span>
</div>
```

the data is set as :

$scope.projects = [...];

inside the controller.

Please tell me what is the right approach for the jquery function to work with the data.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you make use of jQuery, it should really be inside a directive.

Angular makes a split between the model view and controller because it allows you to keep clean divides between your levels of abstraction - business logic in a separate service to DOM manipulation, etc.

The appropriate place to put code that interacts with the DOM is inside directives, by making use of a link function to trigger javascript. What is most likely happening is you are registering the scroll plugin on the container before angular renders any components, meaning the scroll doesn't trigger correctly. Now this means you need some way of triggering the registration of the scrolling plugin every time your view changes.

Seeing as you're using an ng-repeat, that means your view will be changing with your model. You can therefore listen for changes on your array of items that generate the ng-repeat, and when it changes re-register the scrolling plugin on your containing element.

You may need to deregister any previous scroll plugin calls first, but the basic premise is to have your container listen using `$scope.$watch` on the array that is the source of the ng-repeat.

```
$scope.$watch('projects', function () {
  $container.scrollable()
});
```

It's hard to give you a more specific answer seeing as I can't see what you're actually working on, but hopefully this acts as a bit of a guide. Get to know how angulars digest system works and you'll be much more comfortable with the framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot. the only problem i have is that i designed the entire site to work with the jquery plugin...

Comment: You still use that plugin, you just have to get angular to re run it on any changes that angular makes to the DOM. You want to use $scope.$watch because you can then bootstrap your scrolling container everytime elements get recompiled. There shouldn't be anything stopping you from using this framework.